# How to achieve a c++ macros like this

Tags: c++, macros, predefined-macro

```
#define idebug(...) \
  \#ifdef _DEBUG\
    printf(__VA_ARGS__);\
  \#endif\
#endif
```

It is difficult to describe the intention,
which generally means that i predefine a macros idebug which to save some code.
If _ DEBUG flag is predefined, then print the output.
Or pretend nothing happened.

if we achieve it using a function ,it will look like this:

```
void idebug(...)
{
  #ifdef _DEBUG
    printf(...);
  #endif
}
```

Suppose there is a program

```
int main()                    
{                            
  int a = 10;         
  idebug("a:%d\n",a);      
}
```

when we are in the debugging phase, we want a output by complier:

```
int main()                    
{                            
  int a = 10;         
  printf("a:%d\n",a);      
}
```

if we are in the release phase, we want a output by complier:

```
int main()                    
{                            
  int a = 10;         
}
```

Comment: To make it clearer, can you also show an intended use? A short `main` is enough.

Comment: @MSalters, I think you mean an int main. =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do it the other way:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
# define idebug(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
# define idebug(...) ((void)0)
#endif
```

Comment: You could also use ((void)0) instead of a do while loop. Seems more beautiful to me

Comment: @МоргуновВладислав: Changed.